# How do I animate a view on touch?

Tags: ios

My scenario is common I think. I want to animate a focus reticle (just like Apple's default app and some of the other camera apps out there). Is this all done in drawRect:? Or can I use the animation framework right from the touch handler?

Comment: The general approach is to use CAAnimation and/or CALayer directly from the touch handler.

Comment: That said, any real answer to your question is going to need more information about what your question really is.

Comment: Well I don't have an issue with the actual drawing code (however I do it). It's more of how do I get the fidelity I want -- I obviously don't want to lock the view while the animation is taking place.

Comment: There's a hell of a lot of code required to do smooth animations in drawView:.  Even if you're animating some heavily customized drawing, you're still probably going to want to trigger it with a CAAnimation.

Comment: Yeah my goal isn't to take this too heavy -- since it's just a simple user indicator. I think I was thinking drawRect: was the "expected" way to implement this. I'll take the animation framework suggestion in good confidence.

Comment: The norm for something like this is probably to use CAAnimation to zoom or fade an image view or image layer into place.  Primarily because drawRect: isn't reliably called at a given time, it's called when UIKit decides it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Following some of the examples around github (and the internet) I went ahead and just subclassed UIView (drawRect:) and a little simplistic "animateWithDuration:".